# Ajax get call url relative to current one

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm having trouble understand what my ajax call is doing.  I have a partial view used in a few different pages that is called the same way.

```
function showChoice(divID) {
    $.get('/Add/Examples/' + divID, function (data) {
        $('#partialExamples').html(data);
    });
}
```

This works fine on local host, but now I am trying to move this application over to a server, where the url will start with `http://apps/test/`.

This `test` part of the url is screwing up my ajax calls. All other routes leave the full url beginning and tack on the route to the end, for example `http://apps/test/add` and others.  But these ajax calls try to go to `http://apps/add/examples` and completely get rid of the `test` piece of the url.

I've tried `add/examples` (so without the first slash) but this adds this url to the end of the current url instead of going back to the start url.

So if i'm on `http://apps/test/review` and i call this function, it goes to `https//:apps/add/examples` instead of `https//:apps/test/add/examples`.

Any ideas?

SOLVED:

`$.get('@Url.Action("PduExamples", "AddPdu", new { id = "_ID" })'.replace("_ID", divID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
$.get('/Add/Examples/' + divID, function (data) {
```

to

```
$.get('@Url.Action("Examples", "Add")' + divID, function (data) {
```

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your super speedy answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can use

```
<base href="YourOptionalRout" />
```

in html to modify relative ajax path